# Caps lock doesn't work with Danish letters

Tags: keyboard-layout, virtual-console

On the virtual console in 14.04 (e.g. when I log out or switch tty) I have this problem:

The caps lock key doesn't take effect on the Danish characters æøå. With caps lock on the output for these keys is lower case, not ÆØÅ as you would expect.

Changing the settings for Danish keyboard with `dpkg-reconfigure keyboard-configuration` doesn't take effect. Neither does installing console-data and loading the keymaps `dk` or `dk-latin1` (the two Danish keymaps available with console-data).

This wasn't a problem with earlier versions of Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[It's a bug.](https://www.mail-archive.com/debian-bugs-dist@lists.debian.org/msg1212986.html)

This will work around it:

On the computer with earlier version of Ubuntu:

```
$ sudo dumpkeys > mykeys.txt
```

On the computer running with 14.04 add this to /etc/rc.local:

```
loadkeys -s /path/to/mykeys.txt
```